# Python Tweepy streaming with multitasking

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, twitter, raspberry-pi, tweepy

in Python 2.7 I am successful in using the following code to listen to a direct message stream on an account:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import API
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

# These values are appropriately filled in the code

consumer_key = '######'
consumer_secret = '######'
access_token = '######'
access_token_secret = '######'

class StdOutListener( StreamListener ):

    def __init__( self ):
        self.tweetCount = 0

    def on_connect( self ):
        print("Connection established!!")

    def on_disconnect( self, notice ):
        print("Connection lost!! : ", notice)

    def on_data( self, status ):
        print("Entered on_data()")
        print(status, flush = True)
        return True
        # I can add code here to execute when a message is received, such as slicing the message and activating something else

    def on_direct_message( self, status ):
        print("Entered on_direct_message()")
        try:
            print(status, flush = True)
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Failed on_direct_message()", str(e))

    def on_error( self, status ):
        print(status)

def main():

    try:
        auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.secure = True
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

        api = API(auth)

        # If the authentication was successful, you should
        # see the name of the account print out
        print(api.me().name)

        stream = Stream(auth, StdOutListener())

        stream.userstream()

    except BaseException as e:
        print("Error in main()", e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is great, and I can also execute code when I receive a message, but the jobs I'm adding to a work queue need to be able to stop after a certain amount of time. I'm using a popular start = time.time() and subtracting current time to determine elapsed time, but this streaming code does not loop to check the time. I just waits for a new message, so the clock is never checked so to speak.

My question is this: How can I get streaming to occur and still track time elapsed? Do I need to use multithreading as described in this article? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

I am new to Python and having fun playing around with hardware attached to a Raspberry Pi. I have learned so much from Stackoverflow, thank you all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how you want to decide when to stop, but you can pass a [timeout argument](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py#L191-L195) to the stream to give up after a certain delay.

```
stream = Stream(auth, StdOutListener(), timeout=30)
```

That will call your listener's [`on_timeout()` method](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/cd46550b3ef068857f5de9c37bbdd0a72acb7462/tweepy/streaming.py#L122). If you return true, it will continue streaming. Otherwise, it will stop.

Between the stream's timeout argument and your listener's `on_timeout()`, you should be able to decide when to stop streaming.

Comment: Don I like your idea, I think I am going to keep it in my back pocket and give this multithreading thing a try. I think if I can divide the streaming in to a single function (I think it would be main()) and somehow it can update global variables which are then accessible by the other thread, I might be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I found I was able to get some multithreading code the way I wanted to. [Unlike this tutorial from Tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) which gives an example of launching multiple instances of the same code with varying timing parameters, I was able to get two different blocks of code to run in their own instances

One block of code constantly adds 10 to a global variable (var).
Another block checks when 5 seconds elapses then prints var's value.

This demonstrates 2 different tasks executing and sharing data using Python multithreading.

See code below

```
import threading
import time

exitFlag = 0
var = 10

class myThread1 (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        #var counting block begins here
        print "addemup starting"
        global var
        while (var < 100000):
            if var > 90000:
                var = 0
            var = var + 10



class myThread2 (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        #time checking block begins here and prints var every 5 secs
        print "checkem starting"
        global var
        start = time.time()
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        while (elapsed < 10):
            elapsed = time.time() - start
            if elapsed > 5:
                print "var = ", var
                start = time.time()
                elapsed = time.time() - start

# Create new threads
thread1 = myThread1(1, "Thread-1", 1)
thread2 = myThread2(2, "Thread-2", 2)

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

My next task will be breaking up my twitter streaming in to its own thread, and passing direct messages received as variables to a task queueing program, while hopefully the first thread continues to listen for more direct messages.

Comment: The tutorial you linked to is horrible. At the end the offer to use Python's Queue, and add a synchronization mechanism on top of that. Am I missing something? why is this needed? also, the call it a "priority queue" - which it isn't (again, as far as I know - am I missing something?)